# List folder ftp sort() expects parameter 1 to be array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, ftp

My code:

```
function listar_pastas($pasta) {

     $this->lista = ftp_nlist($this->conexao,$pasta);
     sort($this->lista);

       foreach ($this->lista as $objeto) {

         if($this->verificar_pasta($objeto)) {
          $pastas[] = $objeto;
         }

       }

       return  $pastas;

  }
```

Secund code:

```
$ftp = new FTP();
$ftp->conectar("host");
$ftp->autenticar("user","pass");

$array_pastas = $ftp->listar_pastas(".");

foreach ($array_pastas as $pasta) {

if($pasta != "." && $pasta != "..") {

$total_musicas = $ftp->total_arquivos($pasta,"mp3");

echo '<option value="'.$pasta.'">'.$pasta.' ('.$total_musicas.')</option>';
}

}
```

Return erro:

> [08-Aug-2014 06:29:55 UTC] PHP Warning:  sort() expects parameter 1 to
>   be array, boolean given in
>   /home/cassiano/public_html/admin/inc/classe.ftp.php on line 44
>   [08-Aug-2014 06:29:55 UTC] PHP Warning:  Invalid argument supplied for
>   foreach() in /home/cassiano/public_html/admin/inc/classe.ftp.php on
>   line 46 [08-Aug-2014 06:29:55 UTC] PHP Warning:  Invalid argument
>   supplied for foreach() in
>   /home/cassiano/public_html/gerenciar-musicas.php on line 153
>   [08-Aug-2014 06:29:57 UTC] PHP Warning:  sort() expects parameter 1 to
>   be array, boolean given in
>   /home/cassiano/public_html/admin/inc/classe.ftp.php on line 44

Ps: The Same code is working on another server! 
But on my new server I get this error.

Comment: Is $this->conexao being set?

Comment: Either `$this->conexao` is not equal to a `ftp_connect($ftp_server);` ftp connection or `$pasta` is not an existing directory

Comment: Yes iswinky! I do not understand why the same code works on another server!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are assuming everything works as should. But, you should catch the errors.

For example: [ftp_nlist](http://php.net//manual/en/function.ftp-nlist.php) return FALSE on error: "`Returns an array of filenames from the specified directory on success or FALSE on error.`".

You case for that particular function should be:

```
$this->lista = ftp_nlist($this->conexao,$pasta);

if ($this->lista !== FALSE) {
    sort($this->lista);

    foreach ($this->lista as $objeto) {

        if($this->verificar_pasta($objeto)) {
            $pastas[] = $objeto;
        }
    }

    return  $pastas;
}
else {
    echo 'Unable to list files in the given directory';
    die();
}
```

You should catch the errors for ALL your functions.